# Find $f'(1)$ if $f$ is continuous and such that $f (f (x))=1+x$ for every $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

> If $ f $ is a continuous function satisfying $f (f (x))=1+x$ find $f'(1)$.

I just guessed $f (x)=x+1/2$.Any formal method for this sum ?

Comment: What I've found so far is $f(x+1) = f(x)+1 \implies f'(x+1) = f'(x)$ by analyzing $(fofof)(x)$..

Comment: @corbah Correct. Also, 
$f'(f(x))f'(x)=1$ by the chain rule.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a family of continuous solutions:

Pick any continuous increasing bijection $g : [0, 1/2] \to [0, 1/2]$ (so that in particular $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1/2) = 1/2$). Now define $f$ on $[0, 1]$ by

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x) + \frac{1}{2}, & x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}] \\
g^{-1}(x - \frac{1}{2}) + 1, & x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]
\end{cases} $$

and extend it to all of $\Bbb{R}$ by the relation $f(x + 1) = f(x) + 1$. By the [pasting lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), $f$ is continuous. Moreover,

- If $x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ then
  $$f(f(x)) = f(g(x) + \tfrac{1}{2}) = g^{-1}(g(x)) + 1 = x + 1. $$
- If $x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, then
  \begin{align*}
  f(f(x))
  &= f(g^{-1}(x - \tfrac{1}{2}) + 1) = f(g^{-1}(x - \tfrac{1}{2})) + 1 \\
  &= g(g^{-1}(x - \tfrac{1}{2})) + \tfrac{3}{2} = x + 1
  \end{align*}
- For arbitrary $x \in \Bbb{R}$, we have
  $$f(f(x)) = f(f(x - [x]) + [x]) = f(f(x - [x])) + [x] = (x - [x] + 1) + [x] = x + 1. $$

Therefore $f$ is continuous and solves the given relation. But both the differentiability of $f$ and the value of $f'(1)$ (when it exists) depends on the choice of $g$, we have no single answer.

---

**Addendum.** By extending this argument a little bit, I was able to describe the solution:

> **Claim.** $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a continuous solution of the equation $f(f(x)) = x+1$ if and only if there exists $a \in (0, 1)$ an a continuous increasing bijection $g : [0, a] \to [0, 1-a]$ such that $f(x)$ is given by
>   $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
> g(x) + a, & x \in [0, a] \\
> g^{-1}(x - a) + 1, & x \in [a, 1], \\ 
> f(x - [x]) + [x], & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases} \tag{*} $$

It is straightforward to check that $\text{(*)}$ solves the equation as above. Now we claim that any continuous solution of the equation $f(f(x)) = x+1$ is of the form $\text{(*)}$.

1. From the equation $f(f(x)) = x+1$, we know that $f$ is both injective and surjective.
2. Since $f$ is continuous and bijective, it is either increasing or decreasing. But since
   $$f(x+1) = f(f(f(x))) = f(x) + 1, $$
   $f$ must be increasing.
3. Let $a = f(0)$. We claim that $a \in (0, 1)$. To this end, assume otherwise. If $a \leq 0$, then $1 = f(a) \leq f(0) = a \leq 0$, a contradiction. If $a \geq 1$, then $2 \leq a + 1 = f(1) \leq f(a) = 1$, a contradiction.
4. Define $g : [0, a] \to \Bbb{R}$ by $g(x) = f(x) - a$. Then $g$ is continuous increasing and $g(0) = 0$. Moreover, $g(a) = f(a) - a = 1 - a$ and hence the range of $g$ is $[0, 1-a]$.
5. When $x \in [0, a]$ we have $x = f(f(x)) - 1 = f(g(x) + a) - 1$ and thus $g^{-1}(y) = f(y+a) - 1$.

Combining altogether, we find that $f(x)$ satisfies $\text{(*)}$ with $g$ defined above as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Take the $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}{{f(f(x))-f(f(1))}\over {x-1}}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}{{x+1-2}\over{ x-1}}=1.$

So $f'(f(1))=1$.

We now derivate for x:

$${d\over {dx}}[f(f(x))]={d\over dx}(1+x)$$
$$f'(x)\cdot f'(f(x))=1.$$ Hence for $x=1:$ $$f'(1)\cdot f'(f(1))=1$$
$$f'(1)\cdot 1=1$$
$$f'(1)=1.$$

Answer (score -2):

The relationship $f(f(x))=x+1$ implies that $f^{-1}(x+1)=f(x)$. This implies that when the inverse function is shifted to the left by one unit it must give back the original function. Indeed, $f(x)=x+1/2$ satisfies this requirement and has $f^{-1}(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}$. Although this doesn't show that this is the only function, there may be more

Comment: You don't know if $f^{-1}$ exists thus you didn't proved anything LOL.