# value of $f'(0)$ in composite function

Tags: functions

> If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that
>
> $f(f(x))=1+x. $ Then $f'(0)$ is

what i try: $$f(f(x))=1+x$$

Replace $x\rightarrow f(x)$

$$f(f(f(x)))=1+f(x)$$

$$f(1+x)=1+f(x)$$

How do i solve it , Help me please

Comment: $f(x)=x + \frac12$ satisfies the proposed relation. If the answer is the same for all functions satisfying that relation, it should be $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: You're using both $f$ and $g$. Presumably they are the same?

Comment: @jacky Can you show that $f$ is differentiable? In general, the regularity of $f\circ f$ may not transfer to $f$... If you think of the Dirichlet function $D(x)$, you have the continuity of $D(D(x)) = 1, \forall x$ but not of $D(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a partial answer**.

If $x$ is an integer, say $x = n$, the last relation in the OP is a linear difference equation that can be solved to obtain $f(n) = c + n$. Constant $c$ can be computed so that $f(f(n)) = 1 + n$, yielding $f(n) = n + \frac 12$. So, any such function $f$ must be linear, at least over the integers. Naturally, $f(x)=x + \frac 12$ is one possibility. Are there others? The answer is: apparently yes (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711383/find-f1-if-f-is-continuous-and-such-that-f-f-x-1x-for-every-x)).

It is easy to see that $f$ must be injective and, in fact, increasing. If we assume that $x_1 \ne x_2$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\alpha$ we obtain a contradiction ($f(\alpha)$ would have to be simultaneously $1+x_1$ and $1+x_2$).

Thinking about how such function would look like (periodic, increasing, coinciding with $x+\frac 12$ over the integers), I'm inclined to conclude that either $f$ is not differentiable at integer points or, being differentiable, its graphic must be tangent to $x+\frac 12$.

My conjecture is that if $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, the derivative is $f'(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the solution to

$$
f(x+1) = f(x)+1
$$

is

$$
f(x) = x +\Phi(x)
$$

where $\Phi(x)$ is any periodic function with period  $1$ we have

$$
f'(x) = 1 + \Phi'(0)
$$

assuming $f(x)$ continuous at $x = 0$